# how to control volume with slider in juce?

Tags: c++, slider, juce

I am not advanced in C++, but I would like to add on demo projects in juce for learning purposes.
For example: I want to add a Slider to the Juce AudioPlayBackDemo Project so that it can control the volume, but I couldn't get any results in my experiments.
How can you help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtsxE.jpg) How can I encode the volume control to the Slider I've added, which is shown in the picture.

`addAndMakeVisible(volslider); volslider.setRange(0.0, 1.0); volslider.setValue(1.0);`

How should this code be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addListener()` method:

```
class VolumeSliderListener: public Slider::Listener
{
public:
    VolumeSliderListener(AudioTransportSource& transportSource) : m_transportSource(transportSource) {}

    void sliderValueChanged(Slider* slider) override
    {
        if (slider == &m_volSlider)
        {
            m_transportSource.setGain(m_volSlider.getValue());
        }
    }

private:
    AudioTransportSource& m_transportSource;
    Slider m_volSlider;
};
```

Thus you can create an instance of `VolumeSliderListener` and use the method `addListener()` to add it as a listener of the `Slider`:

```
VolumeSliderListener listener(transportSource);
volslider.addListener(&listener);
```

Where `transportSource` is the instance of `AudioTransportSource` that you are using in your application.